# require(public_html/mywebsite/wp-includes/post.php):failed to open stream: permission denied in public_html/mywebsite/wp-settings.php on line 142

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I develop one website in wordpress. but now days i am facing one error:

```
require(public_html/mywebsite/wp-includes/post.php):failed to open stream: permission denied in public_html/mywebsite/wp-settings.php on line 142
```

====================================================================

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/public_html/mywebsite/wp-includes/post.php'(include_path='.:/opt/apt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php') in /public_html/indus/wp-settings.php on line 142
```

to solve this i changed permissions of post.php file. and it worked. but on next day when i tried to open it, again i faced same problem.

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Which theme your using to develop a website??
I think your theme is a issue.. Change any other default theme of wordpress such as twenty sixteen and check the issue.. If it is worked, your theme has some problem..